# Dependency injection in .NET Core 3.x Worker Services: Why so hard to consume Transient services now?

Tags: dependency-injection, singleton, service-workers

I have a Repository service that should be Transient. It is used in many applications.

I have a new application that's a Console App, and current guidance suggests implementing my business logic in Worker Services and adding them to the Generic Host with `AddHostedService<MyService>()` calls.

One of those Worker Services uses that Repository, so I'm also adding the Repository to my dependency injection container. Thus:

```
builder.AddTransient<IRepository,Repository>();
builder.AddHostedService<MyService>();
```

This fails under .NET Core 3.1 because it won't let a Singleton consume a Transient service. That makes sense; you don't want the Transient service to vanish when you might want to use it later. But I didn't ask for a Singleton! What's going on?

The answer is that in .NET Core 2.2 `AddHostedService` creates a Transient service but [in .NET Core 3.1 it creates a Singleton service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51481139/12802). The official line is that if your Worker Service needs to consume a Transient service you should just [instantiate a new Service Scope and implement... a service locator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task)? Really? So now I can't use regular dependency injection in the service constructor?

Microsoft's rationale for making Worker Services Transient prior to .NET Core 3.x seems solid to me: You only instantiate them once, so there's no need to force you into a Singleton pattern.

So my question has a few parts:

- Is Microsoft really asking me to apply a Service Locator in places where it wasn't called for until .NET Core made stuff weird?
- Do I have to rewrite all my Worker Services to work with .NET Core 3.x now?
- Doesn't this Service Locator strategy circumvent the reason why they prevented Singletons from consuming Transient services in the first place?

My point, and I do have one, is that don't understand why Microsoft imposes a Singleton pattern on the Worker Service that makes it impossible for it to consume Transient services and then recommends a workaround that a) is a well-known antipattern; and b) exactly undermines the utility of not allowing Singletons to consume Transients in the first place.

What is going on here that I don't understand?

Comment: I think this is a matter of opinion. Personally I think its better to register the HostedService as a Singelton because that is more or less what it is. Furthermore I don´t think that the "Service Locator"-Pattern is by definition a anti pattern. It depends on the use case and in your situation it is ok to use it. I can understand that it is frustrating to change code.

Comment: The new architecture takes a thing that already works (Transient Worker Services that only get instantiated once), then adds complexity that breaks existing code and delivers no new value.

What can I do now with Singleton Worker Services that I couldn't already do? Nothing. Is it making anything simpler or more efficient? No. Does it make my code more reusable? No, it makes it less reusable.

There must be some tradeoff here, some benefit to forcing a Singleton Worker pattern, but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong! But I think there is a benefit in adding the service as a singelton. You can now inject the service into your controller and exchange data for example. You could do that before but you have to use extra classes for that.

Comment: That's what I'm getting at--the change Microsoft made only affects the `AddHostedService<>` call, which people use for Console Apps not MVC. There is no Controller!

Comment: That is not true. AddHostedService is also used in MVC projects for background tasks. I for example use them to run asynchronous start up logic or to send logging information to kafka. So they are not only used by console apps.

Comment: Aha! Now there's a use case for Singleton Worker Services. I'm afraid Microsoft broke _my_ best use case doing it though.

Comment: Sorry for that! Hopefully you find a solution to make it work again!